# How to filter an observable using an observable

Tags: angular, observable

I have a component which is used to display a list of dashboards from an observable. Now the user needs the ability to search in this list, but due to the small size I prefer to do this client side.

To get this working I added three observables to the component

```
@Input() dashboards: Observable<Dashboard[]>; // dashboards

term = new Subject<string>(); // search term
results: Observable<Dashboard[]>; // actual dashboard to display
```

To setup the results observable I use the following code.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.results = this
        .term
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .share()
        .switchMap(term => {
            return this.getDashboards(term);
        })
        .share();
}

private getDashboards(term) {
    return this.dashboards
        .map((dashboards: Dashboard[]) => {
            return dashboards.filter(
                this.getFilter(term)
            );
        });
}

private getFilter(term) {
    term = term.toLowerCase();
    return (dashboard: Dashboard) => {
        // filter logic
    };
}
```

In the template I have the following

```
<input
    [disabled]="(dashboards | async)?.length < 1"
    (keyup)="term.next($event.target.value)"
    type="search"
>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let dashboard of (results | async)">
        {{dashboard.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

On load nothing is shown, but when typing the list is shown and actually being filtered.

So my question, is this the way to go or is this way off, second if it is the right way how can I be sure that on load the data is shown?

Comment: To make sure the data is shown you should print the data to the console.

Comment: How do you mean that? I have a simple dump in my view of dashboards and results and on the initial state the dashboards shows the data while results is empty. Until I start typing that results starts having info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some other observable things I did I learned some new things of observables.

First I changed the term to a `BehaviorSubject` with a default empty string. This means that there is always an event emitted and available.

```
term = new BehaviorSubject<string>(''); // search term
```

Next was the use of `combineLatest`. That one can be used to use a second observable. The code to get the `results` then became as followed;

```
this.results = this
        .dashboards
        .combineLatest(
            this.term
        )
        .map((data) => {
            return data[0].filter(this.getFilter(
                data[1]
            ));
        })
        .share();
```

The `getDashboards` method could be dropped